# "Page Life Expectancy" in Postgresql

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I need to calculate the Page Life expectancy counter in PostgreSQL just like SQL Server does it.

I know there are no built-in metrics for this issue.
Does anyone have any ideas how this can be done?

**UPDATE:**

Please excuse me for not explaining in detail the meaning of this task.

As everyone knows, both SQL Server and PostgreSQL use SharedMemory to place data pages, which, if absent from the buffer, are loaded from the slow disk subsystem into RAM.
This operation is very expensive. And I need a tool to accurately control this routine. SQL Server has an excellent "Page Life Expectancy" counter that shows how long the data is kept in the buffer and, most importantly, every time the indicator drops, we can confidently say that some data (no matter what) has been dumped from the buffer.

That is, you need some kind of indicator for PostgreSQL, which will show that the SQL data memory pages are being unloaded from SharedMemory. It doesn't have to be analogous to PLE. But something close in meaning.

In my case, I'm interested in PostgreSQL on CentOS or any Linux system.

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose for tis.  PLE is used for flushing pages in SQL Server.  Postgres uses a different algorithm for page replacement.

Comment: I think you need to look at [buffer module in postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/pgbuffercache.html#PGBUFFERCACHE-COLUMNS)

Comment: So what exactly is that number?

Comment: This sounds like a misguided attempt to get metrics/alarms that are specific to SQL Server to "work" for Postgres without modification, but as the engines are not at all comparable that would be a fool's errand. 9 out of 10 times people don't even use the PLE in any meaningful way, it would be worse with a metric "translated" for a different engine. Monitor Postgres the way Postgres needs to be monitored.

Comment: Please excuse me for not explaining in detail the meaning of this task. I updated question in topic.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the PLE is a the average time a SQL Server data page is continuoulsy stored in the cache (RAM).